# Best place to create a cache folder in a Laravel 5.1 environment for third party libraries to write

Tags: laravel, phpfastcache

I am facing the following issue in the production server (not in `local` or `dev`):

> production.ERROR: phpFastCache\Exceptions\phpFastCacheDriverException: PLEASE CREATE OR CHMOD /var/www/curator5/vendor/raiym/instagram-php-scraper/src/InstagramScraper/sessions/curatorlive.com/Files - 0777 OR ANY WRITABLE PERMISSION! in /var/www/curator5/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/src/phpFastCache/Core/PathSeekerTrait.php:110

On the following discussion: https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/issues/441, they suggest to create a folder with absolute path for that library to write to. I was thinking to create a folder in `storage/app` called cache for that purpose, I know that in `storage/framework/cache` there is a similar folder for the framework to cache, I am not sure if I should use this folder instead.

My questions:

1. Where in the Laravel 5.1 directory structure is the best place to
   create this folder?
2. Should I use the `storage/framework/cache` or
   create a new one if so what is the best place to create it?

Reference to the folder `cache` I would like to create inside `storage/app` and the stuff the library will create inside that folder, in the following image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCKAY.png)

Comment: Using the storage/framework/cache directory isn't the best choice since that location is intended for file based caching of the app itself. The app/storage path is a fine and suitable place for this.

Comment: If applicable, be mindful to git ignore that directory if you don't want that information synced between installations.

Comment: Yes, I did git ignore it already, thanks...